# How to draw a weighted graph with snap.py?

Tags: graphviz

I want to draw a network which can show the weight of each edge.

Currently, I was able to draw an unweighted graph using `PUNGraph` of SNAP.

> G = snap.PUNGraph.New()

[image]

However, I wasn't able to find the class for the weighted graph.
I don't want to just put the value above the edge, I want to somehow resize the edge base on the value of the edges.

Could someone tell me how I can draw graph something like below?

If possible I would like a solution using SNAP.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using `nodeXL` which is capable of drawing a graph likes below.
Also **D3.js** supports a lot of good representing features.

I am still looking for more fascinating tools.

[image]